# Swagger не отображает описание эндпойнтов

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, swagger

Сам swagger видит эндпойнты и их методы, но дополнительное описание он воспринимать отказывается категорически. Вот пример:

```
        [HttpPost("add_person", Name = "AddNewPerson")]
        [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(PeopleModel), Description = "Человек добавлен успешно")]
        [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Description = "Ошибка добавления человека")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [SwaggerOperation("Добавление человека")]
        public IActionResult AddPerson([FromBody] PeopleModel person)
        {
            if (person == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invalid data. The person data is null.");
                return BadRequest("Invalid data. The person data is null.");
            }

            try
            {
                _peopleService.AddPerson(person);
                _logger.LogInformation("Person added successfully.");
                return Ok(_peopleService.GetLastPeople(10));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error adding person: {ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest($"Error adding person: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

А вот как это показывает swagger (не увидел изменение описания HTTP кодов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.EnableAnnotations()` стоит?

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) за ответ!
Нужно было добавить `.EnableAnnotations()` в конфиг Swagger.